# how to extract particular property(i.e key/value) from array of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below array of object.

```
data1 = [{id: 111, option: "ONE", actualPrice: 600, price: "450"}, {id: 112, option: "TWO", actualPrice: 700, price: "850"}, {id: 113, option: "THREE", actualPrice: 800, price: "450"}, {id: 111, option: "ONE", actualPrice: 600, price: "450"}]
```

Now i change the price property for id 111 and 112. Now updated array of object looks like

```
data1 = [{id: 111, option: "ONE", actualPrice: 600, price: "650"}, {id: 112, option: "TWO", actualPrice: 700, price: "440"}, {id: 113, option: "THREE", actualPrice: 800, price: "450"}, {id: 111, option: "ONE", actualPrice: 600, price: "450"}]
```

Now i wanted to extract the only particular property in form of array of object for particular key whose value got changed. Something look like this and wanted to pass in function called handleUpdate

So, i want the array of object into below  format
    const modifiedObj = [{actualPrice: 600, price: "650"}, {actualPrice: 700, price: "440"}]

```
handleUpdate(modifiedObj);
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: did u try `Array.prototype.map`

Comment: You claim you want to see only the changed values (the `price` field) but in your expected output you show both `price` and `actualPrice` even if the latter didn't change. That's not clear what you would like as output.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below link . I think it would give you a better insight .
Have you tried `Array.prototype.some()`-> If you need to find any element satisfies the provided testing function .

[Handling array objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Or

You can refer the below code :

```
let res = []
data1.forEach(i => {if(data1[i].price != data2[i].price)} 
    {
         res.push({actualPrice: data[i].actualPrice, 
                   price:data2[i].price})
    })

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data1 = [{id: 111, option: "ONE", actualPrice: 600, price: "450"}, {id: 112, option: "TWO", actualPrice: 700, price: "850"}, {id: 113, option: "THREE", actualPrice: 800, price: "450"}, {id: 111, option: "ONE", actualPrice: 600, price: "450"}]

const data2 = [{id: 111, option: "ONE", actualPrice: 600, price: "650"}, {id: 112, option: "TWO", actualPrice: 700, price: "440"}, {id: 113, option: "THREE", actualPrice: 800, price: "450"}, {id: 111, option: "ONE", actualPrice: 600, price: "450"}]

let modifiedObj = [];
for(let i=0;i<data1.length;i++){
  if(data1[i].price!==data2[i].price){
    modifiedObj.push({actualPrice: data1[i].actualPrice, price:data2[i].price});
  }
}

console.log(modifiedObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out. This code will create a new array of objects `modifiedObj` with only the actualPrice and Price.

```
const data1 = [{id: 111, option: "ONE", actualPrice: 600, price: "650"}, {id: 112, option: "TWO", actualPrice: 700, price: "440"}, {id: 113, option: "THREE", actualPrice: 800, price: "450"}, {id: 111, option: "ONE", actualPrice: 600, price: "450"}]

const modifiedObj = data1.map(({actualPrice, price}) => ({actualPrice, price}))
```

Output will be in this format

```
[{actualPrice: 600, price: "650"}, {actualPrice: 700, price: "440"}, {actualPrice: 800, price: "450"}, {actualPrice: 600, price: "450"}]
```